# Whatsapp share link disappears on Safari (iOS)

Tags: html, anchor, whatsapp

I'm creating a mobile website with a Whatsapp share button. I've checked every single post on Stackoverflow before opening a new question.

The thing is, when i put something like this:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send" data-text="text" data-href="http://www.test.com">send</a>
```

or this:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=test">send</a>
```

the anchor just isn't on the website!

of course, if i put every other link instead of "whatsapp://send" it works.
I need to add: it do work for every browser but Safari.

Is something wrong with my code? Should i use a URL instead of the whatsapp protocol?

Edit: i've tried with the wa.me i.e.:

```
<a href="https://wa.me/?text=asdasdasd"></a>
```

but whatsapp says it's incorrect. Of course, it works on every other phone or whatsapp web too

thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the issue was solved this way:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=&text=https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=&text=asdasdasd"></a>
```

- if you didn't put the ?phone part it just didn't work on safari.
- If yo use wa.me it didn't handle it correctly on Whatsapp (iOS).
- If you use the whatsap:// protocol it didn't work on Safari.

Anyway I don't know WHY the anchor didn't appeared. Did Safari check links or parse html code before showing?

f* you Safari!

Answer (score 0):

In my case a content blocker made the WhatsApp link disappear.

The solution was to disable *Enable content blockers* under *Safari -> Settings for example.com...* in the menu bar.